# How to multiply two numbers based on 3 separate criteria in a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a specific number that needs to be multiplied by the value from a table as long as that value meets three criteria. I have included two pictures below of the format. I've tried using an index(match formula to retrieve the correct number, but for some reason, it is returning the wrong value and I can't figure out how to evaluate the third criteria.

**Criteria based on attached tables:**

1. Match J2 (Bob) from Table2 to a name in A2:A5 from Table1
2. Match L1 (Red) from Table2 to a color in B1:E1 from Table1
3. Check that value from above conditions (5) is greater than 0 from Table1
4. Multiply value from above conditions (5) times value in K2 (1200)(Table2)
5. Return Value to L2 (Table2).

**Table 1:**

[image: Table 1]

**Table 2:**

[image: Table 2]

Comment: @urdearboy thank you a lot. I was completely stuck on index match that i didn't think to use a vlookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a VLOOKUP to import your values.

```
L2 = VLOOKUP($J2,$A:$E,2,0)*$K2
M2 = VLOOKUP($J2,$A:$E,3,0)*$K2
N2 = VLOOKUP($J2,$A:$E,4,0)*$K2
O2 = VLOOKUP($J2,$A:$E,5,0)*$K2
```

Then you can drag your formula down to fill the rest of your values.

[image]

---

Your `0` values will indicate when your `Table 1` has a corresponding `0` value. If you need to show something other then `0` you can house the equation inside a `IF` statement as such:

```
L2 = IF(Above Equation = 0, "Stack Overflow FTW", Above Equation)
```

Comment: I just wanted an excuse to try out a new gif app.